# Android app force closes on some devices but not others

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception

I recently released my app on the marketplace. I tested it on two devices and several emulalators, and it worked fine. However, I am now getting a few crash reports with the following error:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=32665, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.eden.statusphere/com.eden.statussphere.FacebookConnect}: java.lang.NullPointerException*

I pass only one thing to FacebookConnect: a string... here is the code. (I am using easyandroidfacebooksdk)

```
private OnClickListener FacebookonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{

            ConnectivityManager cMgr = (ConnectivityManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);         
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            String status = netInfo.getState().toString();

            if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) {
                intent.putExtra(".myMsg",statusHolder);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection refused",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
   }
};
```

The above is the onClickListener, statusHolder is a string which gets passed on to my FacebookConnect activity. This is the part in FacebookConnect where the error happens:

```
    public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {

    GraphApi graphApi= new GraphApi(facebook);
    if(intent.getStringExtra(".myMsg")!="null"){

    try {

        graphApi.setStatus(intent.getStringExtra(".myMsg"));
        fbManager.displayToast("Status posted!");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

    } catch (EasyFacebookError e) {
        e.toString();
    }
    } else {
        fbManager.displayToast("Fatal error occured: Your device refuses to pass the information to Facebook.");
    }



}
```

The if-else statement I just added to check if maybe the intent is getting passed as null, but I get crash reports about the same issue regardless. I have been pulling my hair out about this for quite a while. Does anyone have a clue? One device it didn't work on was the HTC Thunderbolt.

Comment: Is it consistent in not working on that device? so it fails every time, or just sometimes?

Comment: It fails every time on those particular devices. But ONLY when the button is pressed and an intent is passed. The app runs fine otherwise.

Comment: You are checking if intent.getStringExtra return null, but are you first insuring that "intent" itself is non-null?

Comment: ah whoops that was a bad mistake, and i'll add that as a fix, but the real issue is why would the intent return null on some devices but not others?

Comment: It would be helpful,  if you post stacktrace with line numbers - where exactly NPE is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely forgot about this question, but I figured I should probably document it. Anyway, it turns out it was Facebooks fault at the time. The problem solved itself after a few days of my app being on the Facebook servers.

Thought I should mention this:

Throughout the ordeal however I did a ton of searching trying to figure this out, and curiously enough, this is the same issue caused if the API key is invalid (the one you generate with keytool). So if someone is having this issue, I would suggest to make sure that their keys are all correct. If the keys are correct, wait a few days before publishing your app on the Android Market or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

```
    if(intent.getStringExtra(".myMsg")!="null"){
```

You're comparing the String extra with the string "null", which will always fail unless the extra String you're passing in does happen to be the constant string "null". To compound this issue, you're using direct comparison of the object references, rather than `.equals()`.

Don't you want to be comparing it against the **value** `null` instead?

```
    if(intent.getStringExtra(".myMsg")!= null){
```

Note that as your code currently stands, your comparison will fail and so you'll proceed into the `try` clause and end up calling

```
    graphApi.setStatus(intent.getStringExtra(".myMsg"));
```

where the returned extra is actually `null`.

Comment: but that doesn't explain why it's crashing on some devices but not on others, or am I missing something?

Comment: My suggestion would be to fix this obvious bug, and then try again.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question, but it's also possible that statusHolder could be null before it's added to the Intent, which would also trigger the NPE.